# PHP - Trying to make a chatbot for my game server

Tags: php, keyword, chatbot

Alright, so first of all, i'm still kind of a newbie in PHP.
I'm trying to make a chatbot that responds to the keyword "shut up" from people that tell that to the bot in my game server, but I can't seem to find a way how...

Here's the bot's original code...

```
<?php
$choosechar = "#43CC#1#35#ItsJustABot#%";
$fh = fopen('badtimetim.txt','r');
$word_array = array(fgets($fh));
$word = rand(0,58);
$lines = file("badtimetim.txt");
while ($line = fgets($fh)) {
// <... Do your work with the line ...>
// echo($line);
// Connect to the AO Server
if (!($fp = fsockopen("127.0.0.1", "27017", $errno, $errstr, 15))) {
die("Failed to connect. Doesn't seem like the server is up anyway?");
}

// Set timeout to 1 second
if (!stream_set_timeout($fp, 1)) die("Could not set timeout.");

// Fetch first line of response and echo it
echo fgets($fp);

// Say line and repeat
fwrite($fp, $choosechar);
fwrite($fp, "#4D90#chat#(a)dolannormal#Dolan#dolannormal#".$lines[array_rand($lines)]."#jud#1#1#0#0#0#0#35#0#1#%");
sleep(120);
// Stuff
echo fgets($fp);
}

fclose($fh);
```

What i'm exactly trying to achieve here is when the bot detects this (asterisks should be wildcards or something):

```
#4D90#chat#*#*#*#shut up#*#*#*#*#*#*#*#*#*#*#%
```

I want the bot to send this data to the server in response using fwrite:

```
#4D90#chat#(a)dolanangry#Dolan#dolanangry#no#jud#1#1#0#0#0#0#35#0#1#%
```

How do I do this? Any help is appreciated, thanks.

EDIT: Forgot to mention, i'm using a .bat file to run PHP and the PHP code and not a website.

EDIT2: Made question more specific

Answer (score -1):

```
$input_string_with_shut_up=$_POST['chat_msg']
$output=str_replace('%shut up%','#4D90#chat#(a)dolanangry#Dolan#dolanangry#no#jud#1#1#0#0#0#0#35#0#1#%',$input_string_with_shut_up)
echo $output;
```

This might do

Comment: sorry but that didn't work. i'm not using a website to run the bot. i use a .bat file that runs php and the php file with the code i used. also, i'm still a newbie in php and idk where to place it, so i placed it near the end of the code. (below the "// Stuff" comment). and what i'm trying to do is "send data" to the server with fwrite when someone says "shut up"